# How do I transpose this 1d array to another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 1-dimensional array of job codes that I form, and I need to move that array into another worksheet within the workbook. I want to transpose the list into cells (c2- to - last column/row 2). I know it would require something like `application.transpose(varArray), but I don't know how to get to that point in the printing array section of my code.

```
Sub JC_Fill()

    Dim varArray() As Variant, rng As Range
    Dim x As Long, i As Long

    i = 0
    x = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        ReDim varArray(0)                        'resize array

        Do Until Cells(x, 2).Value = ""

            If Cells(x, 2).Value = "JC" Then
                varArray(i) = Cells(x, 1).Value
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve varArray(i)
            End If

            x = x + 1
        Loop

        ReDim Preserve varArray(i - 1)

    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles")

        Set rng = Range("C2")                    'cell I want to move array to, but transposed

        For i = 0 To UBound(varArray)
            'go through 1d array and transpose paste them (c2, d2, e2, f2, etc...)
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

How do I tell VBA to transpose the 1d array in range("C2") of sheets("profiles")?

Comment: If you "transpose" over one dimension, you still get a single dimension. To conceptualize this, picture a line. Now attempt to rotate it in a way that a given point on the line has different degrees of freedom (i.e. can move in a different direction).

Comment: What is `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count` doing?  I've never tried a `With` statement with scaler value...ie `With 12`--it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start your varArray at 1 not 0.  Instead of `ReDim varArray(0)` do:

```
ReDim varArray(1 to 1)
```

And

```
i = 1
```

Instead of `i=0`

Then just assign the array, no Loop:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").Range("C2").Resize(1,UBound(varArray)).Value = varArray
```

The method you build the array is horizontal not vertical so no transpose needed.

But to speed things up loop an array and not the range:

```
Sub JC_Fill()



    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim varArray() As Variant
        ReDim varArray(1 To Application.CountIf(.Range("B:B", "JC"))) 'resize array

        Dim lstRow As Long
        lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim rng As Variant
        rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lstRow, 2))

        Dim x As Long
        x = 1

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
            If rng(i, 2) = "JC" Then
                varArray(x) = rng(i, 1)
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").Range("C2").Resize(1, UBound(varArray)).Value = varArray

End Sub
```

Comment: after updating my script, I now get a subscript out of range error on line `ReDim Preserve varArray(i)`

Comment: I just added your edits, kept `i` at 0 and it worked.

the only problem is that it doesn't move in the last value of that array. There are 49 job codes and it only fills in 48. any idea why?

Comment: @Profex no it is not, look at the redim line.  It is only as large as the count of `JC` in column B, so no extra items in the array.

Comment: @nicklanta - if you use a zero-based array then you need `Resize(1, UBound(varArray) +1)` in the last line

Comment: @ScottCraner, You are right, I missed that.  Sneaky.  Good job!